# Closure Compiler: size increases because of many $jscomp statements in output file

Tags: javascript, minify, google-closure-compiler

Until now, [closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app) (java version) has done a good job of minimising my js files.  But recently I've been trying to compile a small service worker js file, and am finding that the size actually *increases* after compilation.

What I find in the "minimised" code is a lot of statements like:

```
$jscomp.initSymbol=function(){$jscomp.initSymbol=function(){};$jscomp.global.Symbol
```

I'm just using defaults in the compilation:

```
$ java -jar compiler.jar service-worker.js > minified.js
```

Trying this on the [code from here](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/basic/) (in the section "Service Worker's JavaScript"), the file size goes from 2.6 KB to 7.6 KB!!

But when I run the same code through the [online closure compiler app](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/), I get a *much* smaller file, without all of the above types of statement.

How do I produce the same type of output, without all the bloat, from the local java version of the closure compiler?

Comment: You'll need to post what flags you are using to answer this question appropriately.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth I've updated the question.  Basically, I'm just using defaults.  I've given some example code I'm using, and I note that the file size increases 3x by running closure compiler on it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code you are seeing is the ES6 runtime polyfills. If you don't need them, you can disable their injection by setting the `--rewrite_polyfills=false` flag.

Comment: Thanks.  Where is the docs for closure compiler (java)?  The only reference I can find to a polyfills option is [here](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler-js), but that is for the npm package, and strangely in that package the `rewritePolyfills` option is `false` by default.

Comment: The best documentation is using the `--help` flag on the command line.

Comment: I also needed to add the `--language_out ECMASCRIPT_2015` flag for it to work.

Comment: @DonaldDuck thanks, ECMASCRIPT_2015 was the only flag I needed to add to solve it